# How to add master branch commits of one git into another git?

Tags: git, github

I have a git repository whose master branch is at xxx commit.
This also includes some branches.

The master branch source (with xxx commit) was extracted from some git repo on internet 2 years back. But now the code is updated of that open source package.
So, i want to use the latest master branch code.

But don't want to affect my existing branches on existing source.

So please let me know, how can i get these latest commit into my existing master. I also need all the commits of latest master.

Comment: So you’ll only use master for new branches?

Comment: Is your git repo's remote the 'some git repo' or is this a copy?

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect use-case for git rebase.

If I understand correctly, you forked/got the source at commit A. Then added commits BCD. In the meantime, the original source code added commits XYZ, and now it looks like `A - X - Y - Z (master)`.
Yours looks like `A - B(branch1) - C - D (master)`. You want to keep your old work, but use the new source code.

First, put all of your work you want to save into specific named branches. (Also remember that if you have references (branches) to commits, you can always recover that state no matter what. The following process will *move* branches, so you might want to make "backup branches"):

```
# A - B(branch1, backup1) - C - D (master, branch2, backup2)
git checkout master && git reset --hard A 
# A(master) - B(branch1, backup1) - C - D (branch2, backup2)
git pull source # The remote corresponding to the open source repo
# A - B - C - D (branch2, backup2)
#   - X - Y - Z (master)
git rebase master branch1
git rebase branch1 branch2
# A - X - Y - Z (master) - B' (branch1) - C' - D' (branch2)
```

Comment below if this is not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub's help pages [here](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/#keep-your-fork-synced) and [here](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) explain how to keep your forked repo in sync with the source repo.